# django access related model status in custom managers

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I use `model_utils` library in Django.

I've got two models as shown below

```
class Book(TimeStampedModel):
    STATUS_CHOICES = Choices(
        (0, 'public', _('public')),
        (1, 'private', _('private')),
    )

    status = models.IntegerField(
        verbose_name=_('status'),
        choices=STATUS_CHOICES,
        default=STATUS_CHOICES.public,
        db_index=True,
    )

class Page(MPTTModel, AbstractPage):
    STATUS_CHOICES = Choices(
        (0, 'draft', _('draft')),
        (1, 'public', _('public')),
        (2, 'private', _('private')),
    )

    status = models.IntegerField(
            verbose_name=_('status'),
            choices=STATUS_CHOICES,
            default=STATUS_CHOICES.public,
            db_index=True,
        )

    book = models.ForeignKey(
            'book.Book',
            verbose_name=_('book'),
            related_name='pages',
            db_index=True,
            on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        )
```

Both `Book` and `Page` models have `status` field.

I've got two custom query set classes in `managers.py`.

```
class BookQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    def public(self):
        return self.filter(status=self.model.STATUS_CHOICES.public)

class PageQuerySet(models.QuerySet):    
    def public(self):
        return self.filter(book__status=0,
                           status=self.model.STATUS_CHOICES.public)
```

As shown above, `book__status=0` this code surely works, but I am a bit frustrated because I'd like to use the code like `self.book.model.STATUS_CHOICES.public`.

Please, tell me how to access the related model object property.

If I import `from .models import Book`, it will cause "circular imports".

Thank you.

Comment: Why not `book_status=Book.STATUS_CHOICES.public`, and import the `Book` model in the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I `import from .models import Book`, it will cause "circular imports".

That is correct, but we can circumvent that, we can postpone the import to when we need it in the method, like:

```
# app/managers.py

class BookQuerySet(models.QuerySet):

    def public(self):
        return self.filter(status=self.model.STATUS_CHOICES.public)

class PageQuerySet(models.QuerySet):

    def public(self):
        from .models import Book  # no circular imports
        return self.filter(
            book__status=Book.STATUS_CHOICES.public,
            status=self.model.STATUS_CHOICES.public
        )
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response.

I just thought all imports have to be always at the top. :-(

Comment: @nasiajai: well it is of course better to import something at the top if a lot of "things" need a reference to it. But adding an import statement in a method is a common technique to "postpone" importing until the function is called.